# TypeError: open_read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x

При компиляции данного кода возникает данная ошибка:

> TypeError: open_read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой именно аргумент мне необходимо вписать в  метод `open_read()`?

```
class File:

    def __init__(self):
        self.path='input\example.txt'

    def open_read(self): # функция открывает и считывает файл
        file = open(self.path)
        content = file.read()
        print(content)


File.open_read()
```

Comment: ты пытаешься вызвать `open_read()` в контексте класса, а надо создать объект класса и для него уже вызывать: `File().open_read()`. Про остальные несуразности говорить не буду, ибо их можно списать на минималистичность примера.

Comment: `File().open_read()`, класс не инициализировал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def open_read(self):
```

Параметр `self` представляет сам *объект*, который *создается из класса* `File`, когда на его используется метод `open_read()`.

Когда вызывают метод `open_read()`, он не задевается, так как первым параметром при вызове метода *по умолчанию (неявно) объект, на который метод используется*.

Но вы использовали этот метод прямо на объект *класса*, а не на объект *созданным из этого класса* - потому правило о неявном параметре не применится и параметр ожидается записать явно.

Создайте объект, например

```
f = File()
```

и примените метод к этому обекту

```
f.open_read()
```

или - в одной строке, *когда вам объект сам не должно сохранить* -

```
File().open_read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйтe так:

```
class File:
    path = 'input\example.txt'

    @classmethod
    def open_read(cls):  # функция открывает и считывает файл
        file = open(cls.path)
        content = file.read()
        print(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможное решение:

```
class File():

    def __init__(self):
        self.path='input\example.txt'

    def open_read(self): # функция открывает и считывает файл
        file = open(self.path)
        content = file.read()
        print(content)


c = File()
c.open_read()
```